# Rsyslog Template - Save to file with only message

Tags: templates, syslog, rsyslog

Trying to create an RSYSLOG template which does two things:

- Saves to a specific file using the %hostname%
- Saves only the raw syslog message ("%msg%")

I have found examples of how to do each individually:

```
Saving to hostname file:
$template sampleTemplate2, "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%.log"

Saving with syslog content only:
$template sampleTemplate,"%msg%\n"
*.* /var/log/test.log;sampleTemplate
```

However, trying to do the below fails:

```
$template sampleTemplate,""%msg%\n"
*.* /var/log/%hostname%.log;sampleTemplate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define dynamic log file name in template and then use template for this purpose. You must use a question mark prefix (?) for template.

```
$template sampleTemplate2, "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%.log"
$template sampleTemplate,"%msg%\n"
*.* ?sampleTemplate2;sampleTemplate
```

[reference for dynamic file usage](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-rsyslog-templates/)